# chip seq biological replicate merge after peak-calling

Tags: bed, peak-calling

I have 3 biological replicates for KO condition. What I have done so far

1. Peak calling
2. The removed blacklisted region

Now Im bit confused about the peak merging stage. Here Im trying to use the bedops tool.

So what is the best option in my case when I want to make a combined set of peaks that is present in all the three replicates what option do i have to use?

Which option to use from [bedops](https://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/set-operations.html)

```
 Everything (-u, –everything) or `Merge (-m, –merge)`
```

Comment: consider calling peaks with Genrich which will handle you replicates quite nicely.

Comment: although I haven't used it but will give it try